# how to get the data from API to tableview with segmented control actions?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

i have one view controller in that i added 1tableview and segmented control. 
in that by default segmented=0 is selected and loading data to tableview that data loaded with API.
when i select segmented =1,2,3,4,5 in the same tableview how, to load data with API's.
here is my code

```
view DidLoad
 {
 [segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 }

-(void)segmentSelected:(id)sender
{
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    NSURLRequest *request0 = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"API 1"]];
    connection1 =[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request0 delegate:self];
    [connection1 start];
}
else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        NSURLRequest *request1 = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"API 2"]];
        connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
        [connection1 start];

    }
else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
{
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"API 3"]];
    connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];
    [connection1 start];
}
}

  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
if (connection==connection1)
{
    NSDictionary *dic =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    contestArray = [dic valueForKey:@"example1"];

    courseArray = [dic valueForKey:@"example2"];

    contestIdArray = [dic valueForKey:@"example3"];

    [progressHud hide:YES];
    [self.tableViewContest reloadData];
}
}
```

how can i manage my tableviewnumberofrows in sections ?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)segmentSelected:(id)sender {
    index = segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [self.tableview reloadData];
```

//add this line

```
in tableview delegate 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 if(index == 0){
return array1.count;
}
  if(index == 1){
return array2.count;
}
  if(index == 3){
return array3.count;
}
  if(index == 4){
return array4.count;
}
}
```

same in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(index == 0) {
         cell.textfield = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     //like that

} 
}
```

Comment: put int index; in .h and in viewdidload index=0;

Comment: no need to put objectforkey value in cellforrowatindex? i am storing that value in array!

Comment: check now i have changed. u can also vote the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98236/discussion-between-vaibby-and-mangi-reddy).